# Drawing opposite lines in JES (Python)

Tags: python, jython, jes

So I have a random point on a canvas that will draw a line to a random point along a line across the bottom of the canvas. From that random point along the bottom of the canvas, I want to draw a line that diverges in the opposite direction (think of it like a " V ").

I'm having a serious issue conceptualizing what I need to do in order to accomplish getting the proper X coordinate for the second line that will be drawn (the Y-Coordinates will obviously be equal). I'm trying to do this using the addLine function in JES

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you basically want to just make an isosceles triangle here, so that the two legs of your V will be equal, though opposite in angle.

This doesn't define a strict angle between your two legs (which sounds like it's alright), but only that the x distance between both points and your point on the bottom of the canvas is equal.

Specifically, if you've got some code like this:

```
first_point = (a, b)
bottom_point = (c, d)
```

You want to make sure that the `second_point` is parallel though opposite to the first point, so the y coordinate should be the same, and the distance in the x-direction should be the same as the distance to the `bottom_point`, though in the opposite direction.

```
third_point_x = c - (a - c)
third_point = (third_point_x, b)
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you've got any more questions.